# java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up. at

Tags: android

```
java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2772)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$13800(WebViewCore.java:1434)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2884)
    at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:4140)
    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:1022)
    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$2100(ZoomManager.java:57)
    at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1596)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when i set  "webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON)" happen this questions,

this is my code :

```
    package com.etongwl.test.androidtestdemo;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
        /**
         * 浏览器对象
         */
        private WebView webView = null;
        /**
         * 进度条
         */
        private ProgressBar progressBar = null;
        /**
         * 加载的URL
         */
        private String url = null;
        /**
         * handler
         */
        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 1) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);
                } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                } else if (msg.what == 3) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            };
        };

        @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi" })
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            /**
             * 获得屏幕的宽高
             */
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            // 取得窗口属性
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            // 窗口的宽度
            int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
            // 窗口高度
            int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            setContentView(layout);
            // 获得状态栏高度
            int statusBarHeight = getStatusHeight(this);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
            // 标题
            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.webviewheader, null);
            Button back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
            view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            int w = RelativeLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            int h = RelativeLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            view.measure(w, h);
            int x = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            layout.addView(view);
            // 进度条
            progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null,
                    android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    screenWidth - 2, 3);
            param.setMargins(1, 2, 1, 2);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(param);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            layout.addView(progressBar);
            // webView浏览器
            webView = new WebView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramW = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    screenWidth, screenHeight - x - 7 - statusBarHeight);
            webView.setLayoutParams(paramW);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            // webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            // webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            // webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
            // webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            // webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            // webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            // webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
            // webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            layout.addView(webView);

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * 
                 * @see
                 * android.webkit.WebChromeClient#onProgressChanged(android.webkit
                 * .WebView, int)
                 */
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    // super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = 1;
                    msg.arg1 = newProgress;
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
            });
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * 
                 * @see
                 * android.webkit.WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android
                 * .webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)
                 */
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * 
                 * @see
                 * android.webkit.WebViewClient#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView
                 * , java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap)
                 */
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    // super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = 2;
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }

                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * 
                 * @see
                 * android.webkit.WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView
                 * , java.lang.String)
                 */
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.what = 3;
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }

            });
            if (url != null) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("一个swf文件路径");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                finish();
                // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @Des: 获得状态栏高度
         * @param activity
         * @return
         */
        public int getStatusHeight(Activity activity) {
            int statusHeight = 0;
            Rect localRect = new Rect();
            activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
                    .getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(localRect);
            statusHeight = localRect.top;
            if (0 == statusHeight) {
                Class<?> localClass;
                try {
                    localClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$dimen");
                    Object localObject = localClass.newInstance();
                    int i5 = Integer.parseInt(localClass
                            .getField("status_bar_height").get(localObject)
                            .toString());
                    statusHeight = activity.getResources()
                            .getDimensionPixelSize(i5);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return statusHeight;
        }
    }
```

my project created by android 2.2 and run on android 4.0.4
Whether the installation is android2.2 or android4.0 flash player can run normally.
if i create project by android 4.0.4 and run android 4.0.4 normally
why?
please help me  thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?